# Middle Point from a Route in Windows Phone 8

Tags: api, dictionary, windows-phone, routes

Anyone know, how to get the middle point of a MAP route in Windows Phone 8, or Windows Phone 7?

I have searched but have not found the MAP API that provide middle point of a route. the MAP API just provide how to find route between two point .

example there is a route from A to B . I want to know where is the middle point of that route.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. The Windows Phone 8 APIs do have a way to achieve what you are requesting. Essentially, you are able to get each maneuver in the route, i.e. each turn, U-turn, merge, etc. You can also get the text instruction for each maneuver.

Below is an event handler for a `RouteQuery` completion.

The event handler loops through each `RouteManuever`. You could find the middle element of this collection, and consider that your mid-point.

Full documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244363(v=vs.105).aspx

Example event handler below:

```
void MyQuery_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<Route> e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            // Add the route to the map... Sounds like you already got this part working.
            Route MyRoute = e.Result;
            MapRoute MyMapRoute = new MapRoute(MyRoute);
            MyMap.AddRoute(MyMapRoute);

            // Now loop through the route maneuvers. 
            List<string> RouteList = new List<string>();
            foreach (RouteLeg leg in MyRoute.Legs)
            {
                foreach (RouteManeuver maneuver in leg.Maneuvers)
                {
                    RouteList.Add(maneuver.InstructionText);
                }
            }

            RouteLLS.ItemsSource = RouteList;

            MyQuery.Dispose();
        }
    }
```